# How can I set loading image during post data jquery ajax and change alert msg to div error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show a div if the comment field is empty out instead of showing an alert. How can I do this? My other question is, the data is displayed after some seconds. During that loading period is possible to to add a loading image?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // on post comment click 
    $('.bt-add-com').click(function () {
        var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
        var theName = $('#name-com');
        var theMail = $('#mail-com');

        if (!theCom.val()) {
            alert('You need to write a comment!');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                data: 'act=add-com&id_post=' + <? php echo $id_post; ?> +'&name=' + theName.val() + '&email=' + theMail.val() + '&comment=' + theCom.val(),
                success: function (html) {
                    theCom.val('');
                    theMail.val('');
                    theName.val('');
                    $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function () {
                        $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                        $('.new-com-bt').after(html);
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your code looks pretty good and almost there. why wont you just show the lodaing image before the ajax call and hide it on the success callback? 

Also for the comment, instead of the alert just use $.show() on a div that you want to show.

Comment: before ajax call is ...} else { $("#loading").html('<img src="images/ajax.gif" />'); $.ajax({...  and ...if (!theCom.val()) { $.show('#error'); } ?

Comment: yes. Have you used jsfiddle or plunker before? You can share your code so others can help out.

Comment: No, but thanxs for the help.